# RegEx include to next blank space

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a regexp that will find the letters "AD" followed by 4 number digits. In front of AD there should be a blank space.

Example: `AD1239`
My code: `\bBC[0-9]{4}`

The next part I don't know how to do. If there is an attached hyphen followed by characters... I want them to be included until the next empty space.

Example: `asdf AD3213-4332 asd`
The above should output `AD3213-4332`

Any help is appreciated, Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
\bAD[0-9]{4}(?:-\S+)?
```

Here `(?:-\S+)?` is a non capturing group that will match an optional group that is a hyphen followed by 1+ non-space characters.